# How to wrap / manipulate element outputs on a form's checkboxes html?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have the following form that contains a big list of checkboxes. The first checkbox is the parent of the children below it. In my case it is called "Africa" and the ones below it are "Africa-child" checkboxes. I was able to manipulate the classes, but I can't seem to find a way to add a wrapper div around the "Africa-child" elements. I mean I can do it via javascript, but I was wondering if there was a Drupal hook to add in extra html to the *select* options html before it gets outputted.

The code below is it form data used to build the form. The prefix and suffix is wrapping ALL of the checkboxes, but I only want to wrap certain ones.

```
function hotsite_filters() {

  $form['offices'] = array(
    '#type'       =>  'checkboxes',
    '#title'      =>  '',
    '#options'      =>  get_office_options(true, '', 'local_alias ASC', false, true, true, false, true),
    '#default_value'  =>  filter_get_keys('browse-offices'),
    '#prefix'     =>  '<div id="filters-offices"><div class="filter-header">' . variable_get_value('hotsite_filter_offices_header') . '</div>',
    '#suffix'     =>  '</div>',
    '#size'       =>  11,
    '#multiple'     =>  true,
    '#required'     =>  false,
  );
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for #prefix and #suffix properties of the Form API. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix Any chance you can provide an example of the code being used to generate those check boxes? That might help to say for sure.

Comment: updated with the form data

Answer (score 0):

You could use your get_office_options function and add some html

For example:

```
$alphas = range('A', 'Z');
    foreach($w_question->get('field_option_radio') as $key => $option){
        $options[$option_id] = '<i></i>'.$option_text;
    }

    return $options;
```

Comment: my get_office_options() returns a basic key => value pair. and each value gets outputted into the html as seen above. i just need to know which function is called when drupal builds the form right after the html is generated so then I can at least do a regex find replace to add in my div wrapper.